# Is there a way in Netty to get specific TCP options?

Tags: java, sockets, netty

Does Netty support getting low-level, custom TCP options from a connection?  We need to put the client IP address in a TCP option from the F5 LTM to be read by Netty.

References:
https://www.iana.org/assignments/tcp-parameters/tcp-parameters.xhtml
https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/accessing-tcp-options-from-irules#.U5shRiTSBKQ

Comment: *Java* doesn't support it, let alone Netty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't as there is no support for this in Java at all.